# Implementing a translator service in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, localization, internationalization

I do have a requirement to create an application that can have a language added to it without a problem. The client wants to have a totally language agnostic frontend and all the translating to be done on the backend.

So I am thinking of implementing a translator service that acts like the following:

1. If intercepts the request (a filter)
2. Extracts the header to see if
   the language is not English (assuming it's the default one)
3. Translates each field value with values from a table with a
   a structure like this:

   ```
   eng_field, lang_fk, translation
   ```

Upon finishing with the processing I will reverse the process.

Is there a better approach?
If so please be kind to share it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial which can help you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization take a look

Comment: This only works if you define the translatable phrases in the configuration file. 
I need a solution that will work for values that will be added during runtime.

Comment: you can define your `MessageSource` and custom as well, then you can use on runtime. :) `@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setBasename(“classpath:locale/messages”);
messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(“UTF-8”);
return messageSource;
}`